# How do i have to do to resolver for apollo-client when i cannot use localstorage?

Tags: ios, reactjs, web, apollo

I want to use **JWT** when user login my service.
below my code show that if user get jwt from server, use `localStorage.setItem`.
it works for desktop web, but it doesn't work, ios web.
I think `cache.writeData` also doesn't work at ios web.
I want to know other way to set jwt to storage for ios web.

```
export const defaults = {
  isLoggedIn: Boolean(localStorage.getItem("jwt"))
};

export const resolvers = {
  Mutation: {
    logUserIn: (_, { token }, { cache }) => {
      localStorage.setItem("jwt", token);
      cache.writeData({ data: { isLoggedIn: true } });
    },
    logUserOut: (_, __, { cache }) => {
      localStorage.removeItem("jwt");
      cache.writeData({ data: { isLoggedIn: false } });
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: recommend these urls for you - [Ref 1](https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage#where-to-store-your-jwts), [Ref 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g21uHNIIewM)

Comment: `localStorage` is [available on all major browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#Browser_compatibility), including iOS Safari. Are you asking specifically about React Native?